# For Android, is there a way to determine how many text messages have been sent to a contact?

Tags: android, android-contacts

I'm reading contact data from ContractContacts, and can lookup TIMES_CONTACTED (which is useful to me), but this field only applies to calls to that contact. I'm also interested in the number of times a contact has been contacted via SMS or email.

Does anyone know if this information is available? I've been searching but haven't come across anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SMS, you'll want to access the inbox located at content://sms/inbox directly and perform a database query to count the number of rows corresponding to the matching contact.

Something like:

```
String personAddress = addressFromContact();
Uri smsUri = new Uri("content://sms");
if (smsUri != null) {
  Cursor smsCursor = getContentResolver().query(smsUri, null, "address=?", new String[] {personAddress}, null);
  int smsCount = smsCursor.getCount();
  }
```

Comment: I believe the content://sms provider doesn't work on all devices.

Comment: For context, see http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/be-careful-with-content-providers.html - it's a shame that there's no better solution. For what it's worth, I believe this content provider works on pretty much any device out there at the moment. I don't think any vendors have released their own messaging app that ignores the provider.